# scheduleLocalNotification and cancelAllLocalNotifications are delayed for a few seconds in Simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

In a `SettingsViewController` of my app I created an `UISwitch` that I want to use to enable/disable (meaning, schedule and cancel) a local notification.

I suppose my code is right, since the local notification is actually scheduled when I toggle the switch and canceled when I toggle it again. I check that with a few logs:

```
NSLog(@"Local notifications: %@",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]);
```

I also want that every time the user loads the app, the status of the notification is checked so that the `UISwitch` is set to the correct initial state. This too seems to work with the code I've already written.

**My issue is that, quite often, when I quit the Simulator just a few seconds (sometimes a couple, sometimes 10 / 15) after I toggled the switch I lose the last change I made to the local notification.**

**What I don't understand is why, if I'm quite patient and wait before quitting the application (maybe because I'm doing something else with it), the last change made to the notification (schedule it or cancel it) is correctly "stored" and the next time I load the app the status of the notification is correct (equal to the status it had in the previous session).**

I can only test the app in the Simulator since I don't have an Apple Developer Account yet.
I understand that this could be the cause of the problem (and if the issue is indeed the Simulator, I can pause the development of this part for the app until I'll have a registered account... but I'd like to know if that's the reason or - and this would make much more sense - I did something wrong).

**Someone else had the same slow behavior while scheduling or canceling a local notification? There's a way to speed up the addition or cancelation?**

Please let me know if it could be helpful if I post some code from the app.

Thank you very much,

@cdf1982

Comment: Did you see any of this problem on a device?

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. At the time I had this issue on the iPhone, but since then and with the introduction of iOS 8 (which changed a little the notifications authorization and implementation) I updated my code to the new method of handling local notifications and I never had this issue again.

Comment: Ok I noticed, on device, that after scheduling even only one notification, that it's not immediately available among the listed notifications in the scheduledNotifications array on the UIApplication singelton. It takes a few more milli/micro-seconds in some cases until it seems to be fully scheduled. This had an impact because I was updating UI in my app based on the contents of that array. I didn't see that behavior before, for several years running. For now I kind of assume that the implementation was always like this, only it never caused a problem for me. At least it's not documented AFAIK